# Oracle SQL Developer AutoFill adding Characters

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm new to Oracle SQL Developer so I'm hoping there is a simple solution I've just not been able to find. When trying to use the autofill feature the tool is adding a character to the autofilled texted.

Here you can see see the table I want being presented

[image: Trying to autofill]

When I select it by clicking it or hitting enter I get the extra 'b' on the front which results in me having to delete it for any autofilled text I apply. This happens for any table or column I try to use autofill on.

[image: Extra character added]

Any hints on how I can avoid these extra characters is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've seen this bug creep up from time to time but it's working as expected in 23.1

Comment: @thatjeffsmith sadly I just upgraded to 23 and still get the same results. I've tried searching through google and youtube but just not a lot out there.

Comment: weird, you pulled the version that includes Java, yes? what OS are you on?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith windows 64 bit and yes java included.